# TCEForm Typo3 selectTree not showing pages after 3 levels

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have the following SelectTree of TYPO 3 pages. However the Select Tree only shows children pages 3 levels deep, it ignores pages after this Level.

```
<TCEforms>
    <label>Feature Page Link</label>
    <config>
        <type>select</type>
        <renderType>selectTree</renderType>
        <foreign_table>pages</foreign_table>
        <foreign_table_where>ORDER BY title</foreign_table_where>
        <treeConfig>
            <parentField>pid</parentField>
            <appearance>
                <expandAll>true</expandAll>
                <showHeader>TRUE</showHeader>
            </appearance>
        </treeConfig>
        <items type="array">
            <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                <numIndex index="0">LLL:EXT:examples/locallang_db.xml:examples.pi_flexform.choosePage</numIndex>
                <numIndex index="1">0</numIndex>
            </numIndex>
        </items>
        <minitems>0</minitems>
        <maxitems>1</maxitems>
    </config>
</TCEforms>
```

Navigation

[image: Navigation Image]

Tree View Image

[image: Tree View Image]

Is there a way to modify the number of children in the Treeview

Answer (score 0):

You can set the maxLevels in the treeconfig appearance section

```
<TCEforms>
<label>Feature Page Link</label>
<config>
    <type>select</type>
    <renderType>selectTree</renderType>
    <foreign_table>pages</foreign_table>
    <foreign_table_where>ORDER BY title</foreign_table_where>
    <treeConfig>
        <parentField>pid</parentField>
        <appearance>
            <expandAll>true</expandAll>
            <showHeader>TRUE</showHeader>
            <maxLevels>20</maxLevels>
        </appearance>
    </treeConfig>
    <items type="array">
        <numIndex index="0" type="array">
            <numIndex index="0">LLL:EXT:examples/locallang_db.xml:examples.pi_flexform.choosePage</numIndex>
            <numIndex index="1">0</numIndex>
        </numIndex>
    </items>
    <minitems>0</minitems>
    <maxitems>1</maxitems>
</config>
```